# How to keep multiple desktops static?

Tags: macos, desktop

I am using multiple desktops on my Mac. Depending on how I use them, the desktops seem to switch around. For instance the place where 'Terminal' is (second from the left) moves one to the right.  Where 'Terminal' used to be is now 'Desktop1'. The screenshots below hopefully clarifies what I mean. How can I keep them static at the same location?[image][image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → Mission Control and uncheck **Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use**.

[image]